# Getting an error while starting or creating build for my app. Because of which unable to run app

Tags: reactjs, npm

`Here is my terminal output while using npm start

```
PS D:\runningProject\dashtar-admin> npm start

> dashtar-admin@0.1.0 prestart
> npm run tailwind:dev


> dashtar-admin@0.1.0 tailwind:dev
> tailwindcss build src/assets/css/tailwind.css -o src/assets/css/tailwind.output.css

  
   tailwindcss 1.9.6

    Building: src/assets/css/tailwind.css
  
   ✅ Finished in 4.9 s
    Size: 4.06MB
    Saved to src/assets/css/tailwind.output.css


Starting the development server...

One of your dependencies, babel-preset-react-app, is importing the      
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" package without     
declaring it in its dependencies. This is currently working because     
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" is already in your  
node_modules folder for unrelated reasons, but it may break at any time.
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/vm2/lib/builtin.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in 'D:\runningProject\dashtar-admin\node_modules\vm2\lib'
```

Here is my package.json file

`package.json`

```
package.json

{
  "name": "dashtar-admin",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "this is Dashtar-admin built with react.js and tailwindcss",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.0-placeholder-for-preset-env.2",
    "@cloudinary/react": "^1.11.2",
    "@cloudinary/url-gen": "^1.9.2",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.4.1",
    "@pathofdev/react-tag-input": "^1.0.7",
    "@react-pdf/font": "2.2.0",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "2.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/draft-js": "^0.11.9",
    "@windmill/react-ui": "^0.5.1",
    "ajv": "^8.11.2",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "chart.js": "^3.7.1",
    "classnames": "2.2.6",
    "cloudinary": "^1.35.0",
    "combinate": "^1.1.11",
    "csvtojson": "^2.0.10",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.7",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "export-from-json": "^1.7.0",
    "i18next": "^21.8.5",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.4",
    "immutability-helper": "^3.1.1",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "multiselect-react-dropdown": "^2.0.21",
    "rc-drawer": "^4.4.2",
    "rc-tree": "^5.6.5",
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-beforeunload": "^2.5.3",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^3.3.0",
    "react-custom-scrollbars-2": "^4.4.0",
    "react-dnd": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.15.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.4.2",
    "react-flags-select": "^2.2.3",
    "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.18.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.16.9",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-loading-skeleton": "^3.2.0",
    "react-multi-select-component": "^4.2.3",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-responsive-modal": "^6.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-search-autocomplete": "^6.1.2",
    "react-simple-keyboard": "^3.4.197",
    "react-spinners": "^0.11.0",
    "react-switch": "^7.0.0",
    "react-tabs": "^4.2.1",
    "react-tag-input-component": "^1.1.1",
    "react-to-print": "^2.14.7",
    "react-toastify": "^8.0.3",
    "react-tooltip": "^4.2.21",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.2",
    "react-use-cart": "^1.13.0",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.5.3",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@react-pdf/font": "2.2.0",
    "react-scripts/**/react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "tailwind:dev": "tailwindcss build src/assets/css/tailwind.css -o src/assets/css/tailwind.output.css",
    "tailwind:build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production postcss src/assets/css/tailwind.css -o src/assets/css/tailwind.output.css",
    "prestart": "npm run tailwind:dev",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "prebuild": "npm run tailwind:build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "analyze": "webpack-bundle-analyzer build/bundle-stats.json",
    "cz": "git-cz",
    "release": "release-it",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.5",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.8",
    "cross-env": "7.0.2",
    "cssnano": "4.1.10",
    "postcss-cli": "7.1.1",
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "release-it": "13.6.4",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.9.6",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.8.0"
  },
  "release-it": {
    "github": {
      "release": true
    },
    "npm": {
      "publish": false
    }
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.3%",
      "not ie 11",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      ">0.3%",
      "not ie 11",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: just to double check: you ran an npm install right?

Looking at the vm2 library, it looks like VM2 requires Node.js 6 or higher, so make sure your node version is up to date when you do an npm install